# Skip the first breakpoint in entry file with Geben

Tags: debugging, php-mode

Simple question, how can I run the XDebug debugger with Geben without it stopping execution on the first line of the entry file. What I would like is for the scripts to run normally but only stop on a breakpoint I've defined. Is there a setting for that I've missed? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
geben-pause-at-entry-line is a variable defined in `geben.el'.
Its value is t

Documentation:
*Specify whether debuggee script should be paused at the entry line.
If the value is t, GEBEN will automatically pause the starting program
at the entry line of the script.

You can customize this variable.
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked like a charm.